# vertical Scrollbar automatically moving to top after drag and drop in treepanel

Tags: extjs, extjs6.5

After the drag and drop operation in tree panel, the scroller bar is moving to top automatically. Is there is any way to fix scroll bar in dropped position. please someone help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

Try set [preserveScrollOnRefresh](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.view.AbstractView.html#cfg-preserveScrollOnRefresh) to true on view of your treepanel:

```
  viewConfig: {
     preserveScrollOnRefresh: true
  }
```

Comment: I tried with preserveScrollOnRefresh already but it doesn't helped. I got the solution for the problem. I saved the scrollbar position before drag and set it manually after drop operation. Its working fine now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Also, the problem can probably be fixed if as follows: `viewConfig: {preserveScrollOnReload:true}`